# Copiar css de un elemento padre(del padre) al hijo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Buenas, tengo esta estructura.

```
<div class="contenedor-abuelo(?)">
<div class="caja-padre">
    <div class="caja-hijo"></div>
</div>
<div class="caja-padre">
    <div class="caja-hijo"></div>
</div>
<div class="caja-padre">
    <div class="caja-hijo"></div>
</div>
```

```
.contenedor-abuelo{width:80%;}
.caja-padre{width:30%;}
```

Necesito una manera de asignarle a la "caja-hijo", el ancho actual del contenedor-abuelo, hay algun plugin o script que pueda usar?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, quieres que la caja hijo mida lo mismo que la caja abuelo osea saliendose del margen de su caja padre?

Comment: ¿Es equivalente a cambiar la clase del div hijo?

Comment: Exacto, la caja hijo seria absoluta para eso.

Comment: Una solución: `.caja-hijo { width: calc(100% + 50%); }`. Deberás darle `overflow: visible` a `.caja-padre` para que sea visible el desbordamiento. Si usas un preprocesador puedes usar variables y hacerlo mucho más dinámico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solo con CSS - ocupar todo el ancho del abuelo

Podrías dar al hijo un posición absoluta y un ancho del 100% y al abuelo posición relativa para que lo use como referencia y se salte al padre, algo así:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor-abuelo {
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative
}

.caja-padre {
  height: 50px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.caja-hijo {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-abuelo">Abuelo
  <div class="caja-padre">Padre
    <div class="caja-hijo">Hijo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="caja-padre">Padre
    <div class="caja-hijo">Hijo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="caja-padre">Padre
    <div class="caja-hijo">Hijo</div>
  </div>
```

#### Con jQuery - recoger el ancho del abuelo y pasárselo al hijo

```js
var anchoAbuelo = $(".contenedor-abuelo").width();
$(".caja-hijo").width(anchoAbuelo);
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor-abuelo {
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
}

.caja-padre {
  height: 50px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.caja-hijo {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor-abuelo">Abuelo
  <div class="caja-padre">Padre
    <div class="caja-hijo">Hijo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="caja-padre">Padre
    <div class="caja-hijo">Hijo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="caja-padre">Padre
    <div class="caja-hijo">Hijo</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, opte por usar la opcion de JQ muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

## **[addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**

Yo no copiaria el "estilo" sino asignale una clase.
En este ejemplo se puede ver.

El abuelo tiene la calse ancho80. El padre la clase ancho30. El hijo deberia ocupar el ancho del padre. Pero le he asignado la clase ancho80 mediante `addClass()` asi ocupando el 80% de su padre. (lo que no puedes hacer es que el hijo ocupe mas que el padre para parecerse al abuelo, por ejemplo)

Te lo he hehco asi, pero si lo que quieres es que el hijo tenga el mismo estilo que el padre, solo tienes que asignarle una clase especifica que contenga ese estilo. Tanto al padre como al hijo (widht, colores, tipografias,...)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".caja-hijo").addClass("ancho80");
})
```

```css
.ancho80{
width:80%;
}

.ancho30{
width:30%;
}

.contenedor-abuelo{
background-color:red;}

.caja-padre{
background-color:green;
}

.caja-hijo{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor-abuelo ancho80">
<div class="caja-padre ancho30">
    <div class="caja-hijo">caja-hijo</div>
</div>
<div class="caja-padre ancho30">
    <div class="caja-hijo">caja-hijo</div>
</div>
<div class="caja-padre ancho30">
    <div class="caja-hijo">caja-hijo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, no me funciona asi ya que asignando % al hijo igual toma el 80% del padre, no el 100 del abuelo...

hay alguna manera de obtener el ancho actual del abuelo, guardarlo en una variable y asignarlo a el hijo? o dado el caso a una clase e  incluirla al hijo?

Comment: NO puedes obtener el 100% del abuelo si el padre ocupa el 30% del mismo. El % indica el porcentaje de lo que va a ocupar de su padre inmediato.